# After upgrading mariadb from 5.5 to 10.1, the performance of stored procedures was significantly degrade

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.1

I upgraded mariadb from 5.5 to 10.1.
The performance of one stored procedure degraded significantly.
The DB configuration file is used as it is before the version upgrade.
The definition of the table that the stored procedure is related to has not changed in any way.
What are the possible causes in this case?

By the way, it takes 500 seconds before version upgrade and 1500 seconds after version upgrade.

Comment: Without the stored procedure and possibly the tables it operates on I doubt this can be accurately answered. If you can time and compare parts of the stored procedure on both versions it could be narrowed down. Note the minium supported upstream version is 10.4 if you do the measurement there if you want to report a [performance regression](https://jira.mariadb.org).